# Hibernate: How to join attribute with condition using a third table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following tables ...

```
Object1
-------
id
...

Object2
-------
id
...

AttributeValue      
--------------      
id                  
attribute_id        
object_id  
value         

Attribute    
---------    
id           
name         
type
```

... and entity classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Attribute")
public class Attribute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "AttributeValue")
public class AttributeValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "attribute_id")
    private Long attributeId;

    @Column(name = "object_id")
    private Long objectId;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Object1")
public class Object1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // ...    

    // how to annotate to get all matching attribute values?
    private Set<AttributeValue> values;
}
```

I want hibernate to fill the `values` instance variable with all `AttributeValue`s that have the corresponding `object_id` and an attribute type of `object1`.

If it was only about the criterium of `object_id`, I would write e.g.

```
@JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "object_id")
private Set<AttributeValue> values;
```

But in this case it would fill in also the values with type `object2`etc.

So my question is: Is this semantic expressible in Hibernate and if so, how?

EDIT: I want to highlight that the goal is to have multiple Objects (here `Object1`, `Object2`, ... `ObjectN`) that have no common hierarchy, but all share the feature of having *attributes*. The attributes for all objects will reside in *one* table, distinguished by some sort of discriminator (here exemplarily `type`).

Answer (score 0):

I think the object must be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AttributeValue")
public class AttributeValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "attribute_id")
    private Long attributeId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="object_id", nullable=false)
    private Object1 object1;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Object1")
public class Object1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="object1")
    private Set<AttributeValue> values;
}
```

Hibernate will be generate only object_id column on AttributeValue table.

Comment: The tables are externally created, not by Hibernate. However, how would I apply the attributes (values) to the second (third, ...) `ObjectX` class? The intention was to distinguish them by the type in `Attribute`.